# Bootstrap nested columns

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to nest 2 columns in the second row of a container using the [code snippet from the official documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting)

[When I try the same code](http://jsbin.com/racaqe), the columns appear as separate rows appearing one after another & not as 2 columns in the same row. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

You are closing the first column then following it with two new rows when I assume you want the following rows to be nested in the column. The following changes should do what you want, if I am correctly interpreting your needs

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col‐sm‐12 col-xs-12" style="background-color:red">
        Level 1: .col‐sm‐9 <!-- Removed </div> -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-8"  style="background-color:yellow">
                Level 2: .col‐xs‐8 .col‐sm‐6 bs bs bs bs bs bs bs 
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-4"  style="background-color:grey">
                Level 2: .col‐xs‐4 .col‐sm‐6
            </div>
        </div> 
        <div class="row"> 
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-8" style="background-color:yellow">
                Level 3a: .col‐xs‐8 .col‐sm‐6  bs bs bs bs bs bs bs  bs bs bs bs bs bs bs 
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-4" style="background-color:grey">
                Level 3b: .col‐xs‐4 .col‐sm‐6
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- Added -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this one - I think it is suitable for your problem:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="well">
              <p>First Part</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="well">
              <p>Second Part</p>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <div class="well">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="well">
                    <p>Nested 1</p>
                  </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="well">
                    <p>Nested 2</p>
                  </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="well">
                    <p>Nested 3</p>
                  </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="well">
                    <p>Nested 4</p>
                  </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <div class="well">
                <p>Fourth Part[enter image description here][1]</p>
                </div>
              </div>
          </div>
    </div>                      
</div>
```